# Authentication Based Crud operations with MongoDB database in Asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, mongodb, authentication, connection-string

I am new to the MongoDB. Can anyone please help me to authentication based crud operation using MongoDB in Asp.NET / C#.

Idea is to if user is login to our web application with credential, he/she can able to do crud operation only with his database,not to admin database.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `/database` option in the connection string. While it is optional to use, if not specified, the driver will authenticate to the admin database.

> Optional. The name of the database to authenticate if the connection
>   string includes authentication credentials in the form of
>   username:password@. If /database is not specified and the connection
>   string includes credentials, the driver will authenticate to the admin
>   database.

You can see more about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/).